# How to condition over a vector in all dimensions in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am going to generate 4000 samples(`x has 10 dimentions`) from a pre-defined function in interval (`[-10,10]^10`) (`f5 =@(x) 5*x(1)- 6*x(3)+x(4)^2+x(8)*x(10)`) 
How can I do this in matlab? Actually, I thought that I should condition over all dimensions.
I would appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

you can generate some rand `x` in the range using the following method:

```
nums = rand(4000,10); % between zero to one
% If "x" in "[0,1]", "(b-a)*x + a" would be in "[a,b]"
nums = 20*nums - 10; % between -10 to 10
```

and then apply the function on the nums:

```
I = 1:size(nums,1);
F = @(i) f5(nums(i,:));
vals = arrayfun(F, I.');
```